# Compilation failed to complete:Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

Tags: java

I don't understand why the compilation failed to complete:

```
compilation failed to complete:Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
```

This is what I have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ge.redefine.eomer9"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.8@aar') {
        transitive = true

    }
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.2.1'
    implementation 'biz.kasual:materialnumberpicker:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:FloatingSearchView:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.silvestrpredko:dot-progress-bar:0.1.4@aar'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
    implementation ('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please file a bug on the D8 compiler component using this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533. Please include the full stack trace (from running `./gradlew --stacktrace assembleDebug`) in the report. Also if you have a simple reproduction project that you can share that will be helpful.

Comment: how to send you my project?

Comment: You can add it as an attachment to the issue that you create on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533. Or you can share it privately with sgjesse@google.com and christofferqa@google.com.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with aar. Try compileOnly instead of for implementation

```
compileOnly "com.github.silvestrpredko:dot-progress-bar:0.1.4@aar"
```